# Basic Can Bus Connect on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, can-bus

I have some details about Can-Bus. I want to make a simple listening by connecting a button via Can-Bus using Visual Studio (C++) and print the display of the incoming message based on the button. I need to use the PCANBasic library to use the Peak adapter, but I'm getting an error with the library. I would be glad if you help. I have added the error I received and the relevant codes below.

ERROR:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS1Wf.png)

ConsoleApplication1.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <PCANBasic.h>
#include <thread>

// Button state
bool isButtonPressed = false;

// Function to check the button state
void CheckButtonStatus() {
    while (true) {
        // Check the button state here
        // For example, you can check a GPIO pin or use another input method.

        // Example: Check if the "Enter" key is pressed on the keyboard
        if (std::cin.get() == '\n') {
            isButtonPressed = true;
            std::cout << "Button Pressed!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize the PCAN connection (update this part according to your needs)
    TPCANHandle hnd = PCAN_USBBUS1;
    TPCANStatus status = CAN_Initialize(hnd, PCAN_BAUD_500K, 0, 0, 0);

    if (status != PCAN_ERROR_OK) {
        std::cerr << "PCAN Initialization failed. Error code: " << status << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Start the button checking thread
    std::thread buttonThread(CheckButtonStatus);

    // Main loop
    while (true) {
        // Listen to the PCAN bus and process incoming messages (update this part according to your needs)

        // If the button is pressed, perform the actions
        if (isButtonPressed) {
            // Perform actions here
            std::cout << "Performing actions due to button press..." << std::endl;

            // Reset the button state
            isButtonPressed = false;
        }

        // Perform other desired operations here
    }

    // Close the PCAN connection
    CAN_Uninitialize(hnd);

    // Terminate the button checking thread
    buttonThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried many ways;

Adding Header (.h) File:
Locate the Header File:

Ensure you have the .h file (e.g., PCANBasic.h) that you want to include in your project.
Add Header File to Project:

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
Select "Add" > "Existing Item..."
Browse to the location of the .h file, select it, and click "Add."
Set Header File Properties:

Ensure the header file is listed under your project in the Solution Explorer.
If necessary, right-click on the header file, select "Properties," and ensure the "Item Type" is set to "C/C++ Header."
Adding Library (.lib) File:
Locate the Library File:

Ensure you have the .lib file (e.g., PCANBasic.lib) that you want to link with your project.
Add Library File to Project:

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
Select "Properties."
Navigate to "Configuration Properties" > "Linker" > "Input."
In the "Additional Dependencies" field, add the name of the library file (e.g., PCANBasic.lib).
Set Library Directory:

Still in the "Properties" window, navigate to "Configuration Properties" > "Linker" > "General."
In the "Additional Library Directories" field, add the directory path where the library file is located.
Set Platform Target (32-bit or 64-bit):

Ensure that the library file architecture matches your project's target platform.
Navigate to "Configuration Properties" > "General" > "Platform Toolset" and set it to the appropriate value (e.g., v142 for Visual Studio 2019).
Verify Configuration:
Check Configuration Settings:

Double-check that the project configuration (Debug/Release) matches the configuration for which you have the library file (Debug/Release).
Clean and Rebuild:

Clean your solution (Build > Clean Solution) and then rebuild it (Build > Rebuild Solution).

Comment: Probably should be `#include "PCANBasic.h"` Where is that library located though? Did you link it to the project?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes i added but it cannot be found.

And i changed it to #include "PCANBasic.h" but it didnt work. I guess screenshots cannot be added to comments.

Comment: What is actually in the header file? Could you double-click it in visual studio and show the content? (you can edit your question and add screenshots there)

Comment: hi again, thank you but we made a small change and i have to continue with J1939 instead of PCANBasic. I need to add this to the project in both visual studio and android studio. I'm focusing on the Android side right now, i can't find many resources on the subject. I found the J1939 library for Android somewhere, but i'm getting errors. I want to add the screenshot here and show it to you, if it suits you too

Answer (score -1):

Add operation :
Adding Header (.h) File: Locate the Header File:

Add header file folder directory. Right Click Project-> Properties -> C/C++  ->General ->  Additional Include Directories: Input your folder path.

Comment: hi, thank you for feedback but i have already added it like this ( 
 C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\pcan-basic\Include  ) but still can't find the file path

Comment: Try using full path of PCANBasic.h. in `#include" "`. Did you modify the [Active page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtLuZ.png)?   Is `PCANBasic` in the `include` folder, or in its subfolder?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. yes i modified and we made a small change and i have to continue with J1939 instead of PCANBasic. I need to add this to the project in both visual studio and android studio. I'm focusing on the Android side right now, i can't find many resources on the subject. I found the J1939 library for Android somewhere, but i'm getting errors. I want to add the screenshot here and show it to you, if it suits you too

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Android. You can post a new question about J1939 library.